# Ubuntu kernel - What is "Vendor request failed"?

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have a Dell notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. I use a Wifi dongle that suddenly stopped working and I'm getting a bunch of messages when I reboot the system, like that below:

```
ubuntu kernel [ 1437.231596] mt7601u 3-3:1.0: Vendor request req:07 off:101c failed:-71
```

I reinstalled the OS, but I get the sames messages along with installation messages (like copying files etc).

How can I make it work? Is there a chance it stopped working due to some conflict with installed package?

**Update:** I have dual boot with Windows. I tested the adapter there and it's fully functional.

Also, I'm sure I did an update, but I can't remember if it was a kernel update (I used the Ubuntu wizard for updates).

As I mentioned, I just reinstalled the whole system and keep not recognizing it.

From some commands I found, I tried:

- `lsusb` lists the following:

  ```
  Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp MT7601U Wireless Adapter
  ```
- `/etc/modules` is empty (only with comments). Should i fill with
  something?
- `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` lists Ethernet and the notebook's
  builtin wifi adapter (not the USB one I need).

Comment: I would try using it with a *live* media for testing purposes. Your description, to me at least, reads like a potential hardware issue. You've given no details as to your used 18.04 stack (GA or HWE kernel), so I'd likely test using the opposing stack to which you've currently installed just as a hardware test.  *If there was a recent kernel upgrade, you didn't mention it; where I'd first test an older installed kernel, but I've based purely on what you've provided*

Comment: @guiverc I updated the question. I didn't know about this GA or HWE kernel difference, and I'm not sure which one was installed. I will search more here and find a way to try both.

Comment: `uname -r` will report the kernel in use. The GA is the original (general) kernel and is 4.15 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the default for installs with 18.04 & 18.04.1 media. The HWE kernel upgrades during the life but hit it's final upgrade with the 5.4 kernel with 18.04.5 upgrades (HWE is default for any installs with 18.04.2 or later media).  (GA is for those who prize stability, HWE for those with newer hardware & need later kernels)

Comment: @guiverc After some other tests with a different equipment, I checked you were right: it's a hardware issue. I'm not sure, but it seems to be the USB, cause if I pull it down (making some pressure) it works, but not at the normal position.